# Delete files that have never been modified

Tags: bash, macos

Everything I search for comes up with identifying files that have changed. I want to be able to identify files that have never been modified (modified date/time = created date/time) so that I can delete them.

I have a situation where I have to process thousands of photos, saving edits to them in a different format. If they have never been edited, then I can ignore them. The easiest way to do this is to delete all unmodified files then run a batch process against what's left.

Can this be done without writing code in Python or similar ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are they on a filesystem that even stores creation time?

Comment: As @ignacio is suggesting, many Linux filesystem schemas (like ext4 for example) don't capture creation time, so you may be SOL here. What filesystem are you using?

Comment: I am on MacOS - latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verified to work on macOS:

`find /path/to/it -type f -exec stat -f "{}-%m-%B" {} \; | awk -F- '$2==$3 { print $1 }'`

Comment: Much obliged. I had to change the delimiter (used ^) but otherwise worked fine.

Comment: Sorry, new to this. I tried to vote it up and it told me I did not have enough points. Didn't notice the check mark until now.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
find <path> -type f -printf "%f*%c*%t\n" | awk -F* '$2==$3 { print $1 }'
```

Use find and print the filename, create stamp and modified stamp, separated by *. Use awk to process the output, printing the filename only with the create and modified stamps are the same.

Only issue to look out for is * in the filenames